# ManyToOne relationship between entities in SpringBoot giving SQL error: 1048

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm getting an error in the SQL insert statement for an entity `VehicleReading` which is dependent on `Vehicle` as `Vehicle.vin = VehicleReading.vehicle_id`.

In my Spring Entities, both the entities are as follows:-

```
@Entity
public class VehicleReading {

@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
private String id;

@ManyToOne(
        targetEntity = Vehicle.class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "vehicle_id",
        nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private String vin;

private float latitude;
private float longitude;
private String timestamp;
private float fuelVolume;
private int speed;
private int engineHp;
private boolean checkEngineLightOn;
private boolean engineCoolantLow;
private boolean cruiseControlOn;
private int engineRpm;
private Tire tires;

public VehicleReading(){
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public Tire getTires() {
    return tires;
}

public void setTires(Tire tires) {
    this.tires = tires;
}

public int getEngineRpm() {
    return engineRpm;
}

public void setEngineRpm(int engineRpm) {
    this.engineRpm = engineRpm;
}

public boolean isCruiseControlOn() {
    return cruiseControlOn;
}

public void setCruiseControlOn(boolean cruiseControlOn) {
    this.cruiseControlOn = cruiseControlOn;
}

public boolean isEngineCoolantLow() {
    return engineCoolantLow;
}

public void setEngineCoolantLow(boolean engineCoolantLow) {
    this.engineCoolantLow = engineCoolantLow;
}

public boolean isCheckEngineLightOn() {
    return checkEngineLightOn;
}

public void setCheckEngineLightOn(boolean checkEngineLightOn) {
    this.checkEngineLightOn = checkEngineLightOn;
}

public int getEngineHp() {
    return engineHp;
}

public void setEngineHp(int engineHp) {
    this.engineHp = engineHp;
}

public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(int speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public float getFuelVolume() {
    return fuelVolume;
}

public void setFuelVolume(float fuelVolume) {
    this.fuelVolume = fuelVolume;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getVin() {
    return vin;
}

public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}

@Entity
public class Vehicle {

@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(25)")
private String vin;

private String make;
private String model;
private int year;
private int redlineRpm;
private int maxFuelVolume;
private String lastServiceDate;

public String getVin() {
    return vin;
}

public void setVin(String vin) {
    this.vin = vin;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getRedlineRpm() {
    return redlineRpm;
}

public void setRedlineRpm(int redlineRpm) {
    this.redlineRpm = redlineRpm;
}

public int getMaxFuelVolume() {
    return maxFuelVolume;
}

public void setMaxFuelVolume(int maxFuelVolume) {
    this.maxFuelVolume = maxFuelVolume;
}

public String getLastServiceDate() {
    return lastServiceDate;
}

public void setLastServiceDate(String lastServiceDate) {
    this.lastServiceDate = lastServiceDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vehicle{" +
            "vin='" + vin + '\'' +
            ", make='" + make + '\'' +
            ", model='" + model + '\'' +
            ", year=" + year +
            ", redlineRpm=" + redlineRpm +
            ", maxFuelVolume=" + maxFuelVolume +
            ", lastServiceDate='" + lastServiceDate + '\'' +
            '}';
     }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'vehicle_id' cannot be null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3547) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at aj.vehicletrackingsystem.service.VehicleReadingServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5d90dd6.create(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at aj.vehicletrackingsystem.controller.VehicleReadingController.create(VehicleReadingController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

Here's the controller for `VehicleReading`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/readings")
public class VehicleReadingController {

@Autowired
VehicleReadingService vehicleReadingService;

@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
public List<VehicleReading> findAll() {
    return vehicleReadingService.findAll();
}


@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/{id}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
public VehicleReading findByVin(@PathVariable("id") String vin){
    return vehicleReadingService.findById(vin);
}

@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
public VehicleReading create(@RequestBody VehicleReading newVehicleReading){
    return vehicleReadingService.create(newVehicleReading);
}

@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        value = "/{id}"
)
public VehicleReading update(@PathVariable("id") String vin,@RequestBody VehicleReading vehicleReading){
    return vehicleReadingService.update(vin, vehicleReading);
}

@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        value = "/{id}"
)
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String vin){
    vehicleReadingService.delete(vin);
}
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you do have a String property called `vin` (that seems to be the foreign key) instead of a property of type `Vehicle`?

Comment: I have a requirement for that property, but could you explain me how could i use the `Vehicle` entity instead of that ? When i insert a new reading i will be inserting the `vin` for the reference, so that's why i have put `vin` property.